# How to reshape a wider data.frame to longer data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, reshape2

I was playing with `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` but probably am missing something.  I have a `data.frame` like `D_Wider` and would like to convert it to something like `D_longer`. any way forward?

```
library(tidyverse)
D_Wider <- data.frame(A = 15, S = 10, D = 25, Z = 16)
```

**Desired Output**

```
D_Longer <- data.frame(Stations = c("A","S","D","Z"), Value = c(15,10,25,16))
```

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer(D_Wider, cols = everything())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest would be `stack` from `base R`

```
stack(D_Wider)[2:1]
```

---

Or using `pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(D_Wider, cols = everything(), 
     names_to = 'Stations', values_to = 'Value')
```

Comment: Why it returns values in scientific notations? like using 5.23 to the power +3

Comment: @Hydro You can do `options(scipen = 999)`